# I need help reinstalling or deleting GRUB

Tags: grub2

I need help with either uninstalling or reinstalling GRUB

Whenever I try to load GRUB after uninstalling Ubuntu half a year ago, I am greeted with a black screen (here's a photo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eqpuf.jpg)

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by uninstalling or reinstalling grub? Are you still running any flavor of Linux? What else is installed on the harddisk, other OSs?

Comment: I used to have a dual boot system with ubuntu and windows 10, but i only have win10 installed on my hard drive now. i want to know if there's a way to fix grub so i can load ubuntu properly since windows is messing up

Comment: @TheEarlGrey Yes you can use `boot-repair`

Comment: So you're trying to reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: How would I use boot-repair? and yes, im trying to reinstall ubuntu

Comment: Is system UEFI or BIOS? And then is Windows installed in UEFI or BIOS boot mode? You need to have Ubuntu installed in same boot mode as Windows. And how you boot installer flash drive UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs. Windows 8 but 10 is really same: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system and: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI If system is BIOS only ignore.

Comment: I know my system is UEFI but I'm not sure if my usb is UEFI or BIOS. Also, I tried doing boot-repair but it just says "cannot find command 'boot-repair'"

Comment: I tried doing some random bits here and there and Ubuntu is now loading? So yay!

Answer (score 1):

From your comment you only have Windows 10 installed on your computer at this time.

It's my understanding that the grub configuration files reside on a Linux install.

Your question said you previously had Ubuntu installed on your computer.  You can reinstall Ubuntu on your computer (over your previous install, which you are suggesting isn't working).

When you install Ubuntu, the install process automatically installs a working Grub boot manager.  During this install (of Grub) it will automatically detect all installed versions of Linux and Windows and add them to your boot menu.

After you complete the install you'll have a menu option of booting either to Windows or Linux.

By the way, since you said you previously had Ubuntu installed, when you perform your new Ubuntu install if you choose the option not to reformat your install partition, it will preserve the personal data you had from your previous Linux install.

After your new install of Ubuntu you can configure grub to default to booting to your preferred OS (Windows or Linux).  This can be done via the configuration files that resides on your Linux installed partition.

You can do this by editing `/etc/default/grub`... then running `sudo update-grub`.

Answer (score 0):

Please review [Ubuntu - How to reinstall GRUB2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2). Please be sure to have a backup of your data! Reinstalling grub on a dualboot system *might* cause loss of data. So be sure what commands you execute and think about possible consequences.