# Unable to boot to Windows 10 after failing installation of Ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I was installing Ubuntu on my brother's laptop, but then it failed. It said something about grub failing to install. After that I tried to boot back to windows 10, but it failed. I booted to Ubuntu live and checked if something is missing on the main hard drive. I checked and the files is still there. How do I boot back to Windows and what is the problem with installing Ubuntu? Thank you in advance :)

PS. When I tried to boot to the usb before installing I saw "Windows Boot Manager" and after failing, it was gone. Does it have something to do with the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need help reinstalling or deleting GRUB](http://askubuntu.com/questions/723919/i-need-help-reinstalling-or-deleting-grub)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to repair the grub: [ubuntu-wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Or try to repair windows (https://superuser.com/a/1021657)

Comment: I tried to repair windows and after that it says "No Bootable Device". Still trying to fix grub. Thanks for the answer :)